# Why is the absolute value of the | √2-1| = √2 - 1 and why is the |3-π| = π-3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand that the absolute value of a number |a|, is the distance from a to o on the real number line, and that distances are always positive or zero, so why is  |√2-1| = √2 - 1? Shouldn't it be  √2 + 1

And why is |3-π| = π-3 shouldn't it be π+3?

Comment: $\sqrt2-1\approx 0.414$ right? What is the distance between $0.414$ and $0$? Is it $2.414\approx \sqrt2+1$? I don't think so.

Comment: To make this as simple as possible: do we have $|2-1| = 2+1$, or $|2-1| = 2-1$?

Answer (score 5):

- $\left|\sqrt 2-1\right|=\sqrt 2-1$ because $\sqrt 2\gt 1$ and $|x|=x\ $ for $\ x\ge 0$ .
- $|3-\pi|=-(3-\pi)$ because $\pi\gt 3$ and $|x|=-x \ $ for $\ x\le 0$.

Comment: I do not understand your first explanation. Do you have a simpler explanation or one with less math jargon?

Comment: If you have $|x|$, then all you need is to check if $x$ is positive or negative. If $x$ is positive, you have $|x|=x$. If $x$ is negative, you have $|x|=-x$. For example, $|5|=5$ but $|-4|=-(-4)=4$.

Answer (score 4):

The key point is that taking the absolute value *doesn't preserve* addition or subtraction, i.e. we don't have $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$ in general, what you seem to assume implicitly..

The only thing that matters is that $\sqrt2-1$ is *positive*, and $3-\pi$ is *negative*.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to think of $|x-y|$ as the distance between $x$ and $y$ on the real number line. Distances are, by definition, positive.

For example, the distance between $\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ is $\sqrt{2} - 1$ and distance between $\pi$ and $3$ on the number line is $\pi - 3$.

$|x|$ can be read as $|x-0|$ and therefore this number represents the distance between $x$ and $0$.

Answer (score 1):

So long as $t\in \Bbb R$, we have that $|t|$ is called the "absolute value" of $t$. In essence, it is interested in *how big* $t$ is, not whether it is positive or negative. The absolute value, by definition, is always $\geq0$.

$\sqrt 2>1$. This is clear because they are both positive and $(\sqrt2)^2=2>1=1^2$. By extension, $\sqrt2-1>0$, and thus $|\sqrt 2-1|=\sqrt 2-1$

Conversely, $\pi\approx 3.14159...>3$ means $3-\pi<0$. Hence, $|3-\pi|=-(3-\pi)=\pi-3$.